# Angular.js: make variables survive page reload

Tags: scope, angularjs, reload

Which methods could be used with Angular.js to make $rootScope.myVar variable survive page reload except putting it to cookies or retrieving from server periodically with a $http request?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not use some sort of local storage wrapper like [Lawnchair JS](http://brian.io/lawnchair/)?  It's got an adapter pattern so you can hook it up to whatever you like, but it defaults to local storage.